# onSaveInstanceState always called

Tags: android, android-activity, savestate

I seem to have the opposite problem to everyone else. :)

My onSaveInstanceState is getting called whenever I navigate from one activity to the next.
I checked in LogCat and it is definitely NOT killing the activity.
Also, I see that the onRestoreInstanceState is not called when returning so it must have still been in memory.

I thought it was only called when freeing up memory or during orientation changes.

Comment: What is wrong with `onSaveInstanceState` being called ?

Comment: Just seems to be a waste of time because I have to serialize data and save it to the bundle. Not the end of the world bu seems to be a waste if it is not needed.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think you can have any control on how this method gets called

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `onSaveInstanceState()` is called when the activity is paused. This is because once the activity is paused, Android can kill the process at any time time (without calling any other lifecycle methods). If the activity is resumed before the process is killed, Android realizes that it doesn't need to call `onRestoreInstanceState()` so it doesn't make that call (this is an optimization).

Answer (score 1):

What about the doc saying;

"If called, this method will occur before onStop(). There are no guarantees about whether it will occur before or after onPause()."